# setBackgroundResource for an Image Button

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have included 49 Imagebuttons in my application in 7 X 7 tabular form.and want to setBackgroundResource to all 7 buttons, which are in the same raw, when any one of them is clicked...

Comment: simply add a onclicklistener to all the 49 image buttons and grp the action depending on their ID

Comment: didn't get your concept ??

Comment: I have total 49 buttons...and just want to create some kind of chain reaction which will be caused after clicking any of the button in particular raw....

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == B1||v==B2||...) {
B1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YourRes);
B2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YourRes);
.
.
.}}
```

this should do what you want

Comment: public void setButton(View btn) {
  int x =btn.getId();
  int a,b;
  if(x<0x7f070001 || x>0x7f070037)
   return;
  a=x/8;
  b=x%8;
  b--;
      
     Null = (ImageButton) findViewById(x);
     Null.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_1);
     
     set_null(x+8);
  set_null(x+1);
  set_null(x-8);
  set_null(x-1);
     
 }
this is what i have coded....
where i am calling the setButton method recurisvely...

Comment: No command output when running: 'am start -n com.example.apptesting/com.example.apptesting.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554

Comment: did you implement `OnClickListener`? and are your resources in your `R.java` ? Have you registred your Buttons?

Comment: yes,
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener

and have registerd all my buttons

Comment: ^^ it can maybe caused by your variable `Null` ^^ change it to `imgbtn` for example...

Answer (score 0):

let u r activity implement `OnClickListener`, declare class members all the 49 imagebuttons and assign the imagebuttons same onclick listener.

```
IB1.setonclicklistener(this);
.
.
.
.
```

and in definition of the function group the imagebuttons

```
onclick( view v)
{
    switch(v.getID())
    {
     case r.id.ix1:
     .
     .
     case r.id.ib7: //setbackground to all ImageButtons 1 to 7
     break;
     case r.id.ib8:
     .
     .
     case r.id.ib14: //setbackground to all ImageButtons 8 to 14
     break;
     .....
    }

}
```

Comment: but my class already extends "Activity" class...than what should i do...?

Comment: after activity put implements onclicklistener

Comment: I hv created a setButton functn & implemented the OnClick method,but while Running this application i only get whilte blank scrn.without this methods i am atleast gettting those 49 btns

public void setButton(int x){
if(x<0x7f070001 || x>0x7f070037)
return;
btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(x);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {  
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.Button11:
case R.id.Button12:
case R.id.Button13:
case R.id.Button14:
case R.id.Button15:
case R.id.Button16:
case R.id.Button17:
setButton(v.getId());
break;
}  
 };

Comment: after r.id.button17: use syntax IB1.setImageResource(int id /*of resource*/) to all the imagebuttons to change their background

Comment: i would suggest first get the basics done, u seem to lack basic knowledge of programming a app for android